# How can I show this span only if the condition is true?

Tags: angular, api

I want to display this span

```
<span class="badge badge-danger">RARE</span>
```

only if this condition is true

```
listComics() {
    this.comicsService.getComics().subscribe(
      comicsList => {
        this.comics = comicsList.data.results;
        this.rareComic = comicsList.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.comics.length)];

        for(var i = 0; i < this.comics.length; i++){
           if(this.comics[i] == this.rareComic){
           console.log(this.comics[i])
           console.log(this.rareComic)
           //Both are the same


          }
        }
   });
  }
```

I tried using `*ngIf` and `[hidden]` but no success.

Comment: what is your controlling data/object for hiding or saving? which variable do you want to use?

Comment: `*ngIf="rareComic == comic"`

Comment: Thank you, Explosion Pills! It works! But do you now how can I get 2 or more rareComic? For example: I have 24 comics and I want to display 4 comics with this rare span, do you have any ideia?

Comment: Heretic Monkey, I saw it, but I didn't know I could compare inside the *ngIf or [hidden].

Comment: @CaioHenrique how would you do it in put TypeScript? I see two solutions: set a boolean attribute 'rare' on the comics that are rare, and check that boolean attribute; or add all rare comics to a set of rare comics, and check if the comic is contained in that set. If you can write the condition in TypeScript, then good news: it's the same condition in the angular template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches by which you can show or hide an element in angular

1. By using `ngIf` structural directive. It is advised only when your bound condition wont change often. As I understand, your condition could be

   ```
   *ngIf="rareComic == comic"
   ```
2. Class binding. Use this to add or remove a class to an element as

   ```
   [class.active]="rareComic == comic"
   ```

And active class will have styles to show the item. Use this when a user will interact on the page and is expected that the element's visibility will toggle

Comment: Thank you and thanks to Explosion Pills. It works!